# Cakephp, Authentication adapter Form was not found

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

im developing small app and I decided that i will use CakePhp as a framework, i was doint tutorial to make "posts". But when i wanted to use funcionality `Simple Authentication and Authorization Application` from [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) i was doing copy and paste and encountered 2 issues

first my `User` model doesn't see `SimplePasswordHasher`

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
class User extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A username is required'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A password is required'
        )
    ),
    'role' => array(
        'valid' => array(
            'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
            'allowEmpty' => false
        )
    )
);

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(); <---- here
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
    }
    return true;
}}
```

maybe `App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');` doesn't point in right place but i didn't found a way to check it.

second issue is when i try to enter at login page i got `Authentication adapter "Form" was not found`. Where i can init that adapter. any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the same SimplePasswordHasher in controller as well as follows:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => array(
                    'className' => 'Simple',
                    'hashType' => 'sha256'
                )
            )
        ),
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'index'
        )
    )
);
```

Hope it helps